# Cloud-Based Time Tracking Software

Tags: time-management, timekeeping

I'm looking for a cloud-based time tracking service for a 20 person company which allows employees to be logged in throughout the day and choose a work category from a drop down menu, choose the client ID number, enter the amount of time they spent working on a task for that client ID and briefly describe the task. Anyone have suggestions and could you include why you suggest it?

Comment: http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/q/698/4271

Comment: Maybe move this question to: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are a huge amount of options out there that will fulfil all your requirements. A few populair ones:

- http://toggl.com
- http://getharvest.com
- http://paymo.biz
- http://letsfreckle.com
- http://yanomo.com

**Disclaimer:** As I'm the CTO for [Yanomo](http://www.yanomo.com) I am biased. I will comment on it's capabilities and leave judging it to others.

- Calendar based with Google and/or Outlook integration
- As well as Matrix based time entry (excel style)
- Support for business units so and thus also good support for larger/growing organisations (though for 20 users you might still be fine without them)
- Very flexible activity/rate support allowing for global/business unit/user/client/project/sub-project (or a combination thereof) rates
- Labor and expense budgeting on the basis of lump sum/monthly retainer/weekly retainer
- Support for sub-projects to any depth you need
- Very flexible reporting on client/project/user/activity/business unit/monthly/weekly basis
- All exportable to CSV
- API available

[image: Screenshot of the calendar entry screen]